# Create a realm object during a Realm Migration

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-migration

Are you able to create a realm Object during a migration?  I am wanting to extract part of an existing realm object and create a new object with that data, but the migration always hangs up.  Here is my migration code

```
private class var migrationBlock: MigrationBlock {
    return { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
            print("Shema Version 0")
            migration.enumerate(Transaction.className(), { (oldObject, newObject) -> Void in
                let oldDate = oldObject!["date"] as! NSDate
                let newTransactionDate = TransactionDate()
                newTransactionDate.date = oldDate
                try! Realm.getRealm().write { Realm.getRealm().add(newTransactionDate, update: true) }
                newObject!["_date"] = newTransactionDate
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `Migration.create(_:value:)` to create object during migration.

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Migration.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift9Migration6createFS0_FTSS5valuePSs9AnyObject__CS_13DynamicObject

It returns `MigrationObject`'s instance. So you should use subscripting to assign a value to its property.

```
let oldDate = oldObject!["date"] as! NSDate

let newTransactionDate = migration.create(TransactionDate.className())
newTransactionDate["date"] = oldDate

newObject!["_date"] = newTransactionDate
```